# Remove tags from Rich Text Area

Tags: apex, trigger, richtextarea, formatting

This is probably super simple but I can't figure it out. I am combining the text from two rich text area fields into a long text area field and I am getting all the formatting tags in the result.  Is there an easy way to get just the text from the rich text area field?

```
     string msgToSup = 'Privacy Officer Message: ' + SPM.Message_To_Supervisor__c 
        + '\n\n' + 'Security Officer Message: ' + SPM.Security_Officer_Message_to_Supervisor__c
        + '\n\n' + '***Please see the PDF in the Files section for event details.***';
```

Results in this:
[image]

Comment: a RTF is by definition going to have HTML tags. What is the intended destination of the `msgToSup`? If part of an HTML email, you'll want the tags

Comment: how did you bind in to UI, can you provide Html code ?

Comment: @sdandamud1 It's literally just a plain text field on a record detail page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stripHtmlTags()` function to remove all HTML tags.

```
 string msgToSup = 'Privacy Officer Message: ' 
    + SPM.Message_To_Supervisor__c.stripHtmlTags()
    + '\n\n' + 'Security Officer Message: ' 
    + SPM.Security_Officer_Message_to_Supervisor__c.stripHtmlTags()
    + '\n\n' + '***Please see the PDF in the Files section for event details.***';
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, you always have the easiest solutions!